# Using openssl-encrypted field to filter on a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, openssl

I have a MySQL table where I store data encrypted with `openssl`.

Lets say I have a MySQL table called `friends` with fields `id, name, surname`.

I just want to encrypt the field `name`. So I encrypt it using `openssl_public_encrypt` and then I save it in the table. That works fine.

When I need to read a record, I select it and decrypt `name` using `openssl_private_decrypt` and I can read it. It also works fine.

Now here is my problem. Lets say I need to find all the records with `name = 'carlos'`

The first thing I did (I am a beginner in openssl) was to encrypt `'carlos'` and use that value as the condition:

```
<?php
    openssl_public_encrypt('carlos', $encrypted, $myPublicKey);
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM friends WHERE name ="' . $encrypted . '"; ';
?>
```

But then I realized `openssl_public_encrypt` always returns a different value for the same input. So I can't replicate the first encrypted value.

Now I'm thinking that is impossible to use that field as condition.

**THE QUESTION**: Is there a way I can use openssl-encrypted fields as a condition in MySQL to filter?

Answer (score 1):

That won't work because the output of `openssl_public_encrypt()` for the same name will be different each time.

For searchable fields you could consider adding a hashed column of that field, using SHA1 or MD5 even, which always produces the same value for the same name:

```
$hashed_name = sha1('carlos');
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE name_hashed = '%s'", $hashed_name);
```

To be sure you have no hash collisions you need to inspect each row in the query result as well.

The biggest downside is that for every INSERT and UPDATE statement you will have to maintain the hashed version as well.

If you feel paranoid you could also use a keyed hash, using [`hash_hmac()`](http://php.net/hash_hmac), passing in your secret key.